# How to compare two arrays elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following two arrays and want to compare if element of array1 is partially matching with the array2 then it should return true. for example last element of array1 is partially matching with the last element of array2.

```
    array1 = ["https://www.norcalunitedway.org/node/61/webform/confirmation", "https://www.norcalunitedway.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2",
"https://www.norcalunitedway.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2"]

array2 = ["https://www.norcalunitedway.org/contact-uwnc?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund",
"https://www.norcalunitedway.org/wildfire-recovery-disaster?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund",
"https://www.norcalunitedway.org/our-work?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund",
"https://www.norcalunitedway.org/services?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund",
"https://www.norcalunitedway.org/about-us?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund",
"https://www.norcalunitedway.org/frequently-asked-questions-faq?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund",
"https://www.norcalunitedway.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2&utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund"]
```

I tried with following JavaScript code but it is not working

```
 const partmatch = array1.filter(element => array2.includes(element));
   console.log(partmatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#some` along with `Array#includes`.

```js
const array1=["https://www.norcalunitedway.org/node/61/webform/confirmation","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2"],array2=["https://www.norcalunitedway.org/contact-uwnc?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/wildfire-recovery-disaster?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/our-work?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/services?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/about-us?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/frequently-asked-questions-faq?utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund","https://www.norcalunitedway.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2&utm_source=localiq&utm_medium=xmo&utm_campaign=wildfirefund"];
let matches = array1.some(x => array2.some(y => y.includes(x)));
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but this is not working at my end.